# Angular 2 Firebase how to get array in object

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this array from my database :

[image]

By this function :

```
getMembers(){
  this.db.list(`projects/${this.auth.userId}/${this.uploadService.pro.name}/teams/`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes =>
      changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
    )
  ).subscribe((data:any) => 
    console.log(data)
   this.members = data;
    )
}
```

How to display members in ngFor ?

My try (first ngFor is teams - second one is for members) :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of teams">
<p>{{item.name}}</p>
<p *ngFor="let member of item.members">{{member}}</p> //does not work
</div>
```

Error for `let member of item.member` :

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Teams are only - name:string - members are in teams.

```
export Interface Teams {
name: string;
}

export Interface Members {
name: string;
}
```

At first I upload team - for example "Programmers". Then I add members to that Team. And it looks like :

```
8468as6d84a6s8d4a6s8d4 {
name: Programmers;
members: {
FirstMember,
SeconndMemeber...
}
}
```

Comment: can you post JSON data here instead of Image? also what data does `teams` contains?

Comment: what is teams here? your variable shows it should be just members

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are getting error, because your `members` is object and object isn't iterable, and `*ngFor` supports only `iterables` for example arrays, maps and so on..., so you can:

use `Object.keys()`, which will return keys of objects in new array,

**NOTE** that `Object` isn't accessible in the template, so you should create a pipe or define a method in the component.ts which will do the job,
 for example

```
objectKeys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
}

<div *ngFor="let item of teams">
<p>{{item.name}}</p>
<p *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(item.members)">{{item.members[key].name}}</p>
</div>
```

or another option you can use `Object.values()`, which will return values of objects in new array

```
objectValues(obj) {
   return Object.values(obj);
}
<div *ngFor="let item of teams">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <p *ngFor="let member of objectValues(item.members)">{{member.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined or  Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

Comment: @Angulandy2 I have updated my answer, please check again

Comment: It cant work because objectValues got "item" which is not defined.

Comment: error : item is not defined in function objectValues(obj) or objectKeys(obj)

Comment: As you can see i did that

Comment: @Angulandy2 ah sorry I fixed it, it was typo

Comment: Now I get for both examples : Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: @Angulandy2 did you check my last update?, please check again

Comment: Yes I did with the last. Same error, console.log(obj) gives keys and values, but convert didnt happen.

Comment: @Angulandy2 it should work, or you haven't `members` property in your `item` object

Comment: Yes  I dont have members in my item (Teams interface) i have two different interfaces - "Teams" and "Members" , how to make it in one ?

Comment: then how you have members in your console image ?, also you can add Members interface inside Teams interface

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184228/discussion-between-angulandy2-and-artyom-amiryan).